# Changing Resolution with Wine App Opened freezes screen

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, resolution

Whenever I try to change the resolution using nvidia-setting or the display manager with any Wine program that uses graphics (Dead island, Most Wanted, anything with graphics really) the screen freezes. Am stuck there until I press escape, at least in the nvidia-setting since I have a couple of seconds to press escape and go back to the previous resolution settings.

What can be done about this or is there a bug already mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a known bug, but for your WINE applications, you can have WINE use a window. It will allow your applications to have their own "screen size" without affecting the global resolution.

Comment: That is correct and it works for most apps but in this particular case which is the first for me really, when I have it in windows mode (not getting the resolution from the actual ubuntu resolution) it still creates the error. Everything freezes. Using 1.3.31 in this case.